# Line separator in css block elements

Tags: css

What does mean "line separator" in the following context: `Block elements is generating line separator after and before their blocks.` Can you shoh me an example?

Comment: It is very ambiguous. Could be a border. Could be a margin. Maybe some padding. A background image? Can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

it means that they take a width of a full row. Each piece of content before, or after the element, will be shown on top, on bottom of the `display:block` element. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hc85E/. You can think like this: `<br/> block element <br/>`